# Transposing a matrix in-place using the "follow-the-cycles" algorithm

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to implement the ["follow-the-cycles"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition#Non-square_matrices%3a_Following_the_cycles) algorithm for transposing a matrix in-place. The matrix is stored in an array in row-major order. I am also using a boolean array to keep track of the visited locations. Here is what I have so far:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_matrix(const int *mtx, int rows, int columns)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
      printf("%2d ", mtx[(i * columns) + j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}

void transpose_matrix(int *mtx, int rows, int columns)
{
  int size = rows * columns;
  bool *visited = malloc(sizeof (bool) * size);

  // ...

  free(visited);
}

int main(void)
{
  enum { ROWS = 4, COLUMNS = 3 };
  int mtx[ROWS * COLUMNS] = {
     1,  2,  3,
     4,  5,  6,
     7,  8,  9,
    10, 11, 12
  };

  printf("Original:\n");
  print_matrix(mtx, ROWS, COLUMNS);

  printf("\nTransposed:\n");
  transpose_matrix(mtx, ROWS, COLUMNS);
  print_matrix(mtx, ROWS, COLUMNS);

  return 0;
}
```

I do not quite understand some parts of the pseudocode so I am having trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is first to find an un-transposed cycle. This is any position `p` where the bool array is false. Then calculate the transposed location `q`, save the value there `a[q]` temporarily, copy `a[p]` to `a[q]`, update the boolean array accordingly, then set `p` to `q` and repeat using the last temporarily saved value until `q` turns out to be already transposed.

That means you've reached the end of the cycle. Go look for the next one. In code, this means you'll have an outer loop searching the bool array for false values and an inner one traversing cycles.

When the bool array is completely true, you're done.

If the matrix is square, all cycles have length 2. Rectangular arrays will have longer ones.

To pull this off, you must be able to "decode" and "encode" row/column index pairs `(i,j)` from/to linear array positions.  If the array is stored in row major order, decoding is `p = i * n_cols + j`. Encoding is `i(p) = p / n_cols`, `j(p) = p % n_cols`.

For example, if `p` isn't transposed yet, you get it's transposed location with

```
q = j(p) * n_cols + i(p) = (p % n_cols) * n_cols + p / n_cols
```

I won't spoil the rest of your fun.